# javascript promise inside object

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I can get to work a promise inside the object "addable:". after saving the new client the id added to the slimselect need to wait for the new _id.
Thanks

Pay to*

```
var Datastore = require('nedb');
var dclipro = new Datastore({filename: '/data/clipro.db', autoload: true});

var selectclipro = new SlimSelect({
                select: '#bcofid_clipro',
                valuesUseText: false,
                addable: function (value) {
                    var newid = "";

                    var agrabar = {
                          name: value,
                          last_idcuenta: "null",
                          email: "notdefined@gmail.com",
                          memo: "not available",
                          auditlog: moment().format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a')
                    }
                    dclipro.update({name: value}, agrabar, options, function (err, numReplaced, upsert) {

                        if (err) {
                            console.error(err);
                        }
                        newid = upsert._id;

                    })
                    iziToast.show({
                        title: 'Bank',
                        message: 'New Payee has been saved successfully',
                        position: 'topRight'
                    });
                    return { text: value, value: newid }

              },
              onChange: (info) => {
                console.log('elegido : value ' +info.value);
                console.log('elegido : text ' +info.text);
              }
            })
```

Comment: So where is the promise? How did you try to use one?

Comment: Hard to parse out what you're asking here. Looks like you need `addable` to return the object `{text: value, value: newid}`. If you can't return a Promise from `addable`, that will resolve to that, then not sure you can, with `dclipro.update()` being your async request (I'm guessing). As the code works now, the `iziToast.show()` and the return would both happen while your asnychronous request is still firing. You wouldn't want to show that success until you've verified you have no error (so in the `update` callback), and you can't return what you don't have.

Answer (score 0):

SlimSelect, wow is this thing dated. From the documentation, it looks like your `return` object is optional, and that you should be able to do something like `selectclipro.setData(myNewValue)` inside your promise callback, as long as `addable` can actually see `selectclipro`. (Make sure you read the rest of my comments above)